# Sum all values in dataframe column grouped by one column and depending on other column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, apply

I have a number for each individual during a specific month represented by an integer. I need to add those numbers for each individual until the specified date for each row. I would like to use the apply function on the python DataFrame to make it scalable.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'number': [10, 20 , 30, 40, 50], 'individual': ["John", "John" , "Eleonor", "Eleonor", "Eleonor"], 'date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

df=

```
   number individual  date
0      10       John     1
1      20       John     2
2      30    Eleonor     3
3      40    Eleonor     4
4      50    Eleonor     5
```

I want to sum the numbers when the date is strictly lower than the one in the row and put NA if there is no row with a date that meets the condition.
Here the result would be:

```
   number individual  date
0      NA       John     1
1      10       John     2
2      NA    Eleonor     3
3      30    Eleonor     4
4      70    Eleonor     5
```

Comment: _"when the date is strictly lower than the one in the row"_ Im not sure what you mean

Comment: For each row, the values need to be summed up only if the date has an integer lower than the one in the current row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the apply method as requested, which allows the use with dask:

```
df['number'] = df.groupby("individual")['number'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().sum().shift())
```

which yields

```
   number individual  date
0     NaN       John     1
1    10.0       John     2
2     NaN    Eleonor     3
3    30.0    Eleonor     4
4    70.0    Eleonor     5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [10, 20 , 30, 40, 50], 
                   'ind': ["John", "John" , "Eleonor", "Eleonor", "Eleonor"], 
                   'date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df['x'] = df.groupby('ind')['num'].shift()
df['y'] = df.groupby('ind')['x'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

yields

```
   num      ind  date     x     y
0   10     John     1   NaN   NaN
1   20     John     2  10.0  10.0
2   30  Eleonor     3   NaN   NaN
3   40  Eleonor     4  30.0  30.0
4   50  Eleonor     5  40.0  70.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it was that easy. When I do it on my dataframe, I get AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'shift'. Do you know why?

Comment: I found why, it's because I'm using dask, which does not support shift(). Thank you for your answer!